# Start up problems-Toyota Celica

Tags: toyota, starting, celica

Having some problems starting car.  No clicking noise but dashboard lights up.  Then I fumble with a wire under the dashboard and suddenly it starts.  What wire can that be? My friend tell me its a thick black wire but he doesn't know what wire it is?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a partially disconnected/damaged ignition wire. You'll have to poke around a good bit to find exactly which wire it is.

What year is your Celica?

My buddy had a similar issue on a Supra, and he fixed it by installing a new starter relay and running a new wire to the starter. He just decided it was too much work to find which wire in such a cluttered harness.